# Execvp with three elements

Tags: c, execvp

I am trying to do the following:

```
execvp(command[0][0], argument[0], '&');
```

Which works when it is not in background mode, that is to say:

```
execvp(command[0][0], argument[0]);
```

Is it necessary to create an extra array to concatenate the character & to the end of `argument`, or is there any other way to insert the background option at the end of execvp command?

Comment: `&` is not an argument, but rather parsed by the shell.

Comment: For clarity if you're doing this for background mode, then the `&` is not an argument to a program.  Its parsed by the shell your in (eg bash) and is equivalent to first calling `fork()`.  Maybe take a look at: http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/sum01/example1.html

Answer (score 0):

**To answer what you've asked:**

If you want to pass an extra argument you will need to concatenate to the array.  This may mean building a new array.  Considder using `memcpy()` to make life easier when copying.

**But to asnwer what you are looking for (running in the background)**

You can not do something in background mode with this.  execvp replaces your entire process image with the command (first argument).

Example taken from: http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/sum01/example1.html

If you want to run something in the background you need to fork first:

```
int runcmd(char *cmd)
{
  char* argv[MAX_ARGS];
  pid_t child_pid;
  int child_status;

  parsecmd(cmd,argv);
  child_pid = fork();
  if(child_pid == 0) {
    /* This is done by the child process. */

    execvp(argv[0], argv);

    /* If execvp returns, it must have failed. */

    printf("Unknown command\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
     /* This is run by the parent.  Wait for the child
        to terminate.  If you want to run in the background then 
        you could remove this code.  It's equivalent to "wait" 
        on the shell. */

     do {
       pid_t tpid = wait(&child_status);
       if(tpid != child_pid) process_terminated(tpid);
     } while(tpid != child_pid);

     return child_status;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `execvp()` function expects exactly two arguments, the name of the binary to execute and a `NULL`-terminated array of pointers to the command arguments.  Passing more or fewer arguments results in undefined behavior.  Passing arguments of types different than those expected may compile, but probably does not have the result you wanted.

So yes, if you wanted to take an existing argument array and add another argument then you would need to make a copy with space for an additional element.  Note, too, that '&' is a `char` literal, not a string literal.  The distinction is immense.

With all that said, I observe, as others did, that giving "&" as an argument to the program will *not* have the result of running the program in the background, and more generally that `execvp()` and the other exec-family functions may not have quite the behavior you expect.  In particular, be aware that the exec functions normally do not return.  Usually, one `fork()`s first and performs the exec in the child process, which inherently provides the background process behavior.

Alternatively, it may be that you'll find the `system()` function more convenient, as it uses the shell to run the command you specify.